# LambdaClient - Run Time Exception: Connection pool shut down

Tags: java, aws-lambda, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm getting a `Connection pool shut down` exception when using a LambdaClient. The LambdaClient is created each time I need to call the lambda as the config can change.

After what appears to be a random number of calls it starts failing and throwing a `Connection pool shut down` exception. It will then fail with every subsequent call and is only resolved by restarting the service.

It's strange as we're creating the LambdaClient each time and it should call `.close()` as it's using a try-with-resource statement. It's as though there is something stored globally that is being shut down which means any new LambdaClients will fail to make a connection.

The exception doesn't give any more information on this including line numbers.

```
try (LambdaClient client = LambdaClient.builder()
        .region(region)
        .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
        .overrideConfiguration(
                builder -> builder.apiCallTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(118))
                        .apiCallAttemptTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(118))
                        .retryPolicy(RetryPolicy.none()))
        .httpClientBuilder(ApacheHttpClient.builder()
                .maxConnections(10)
                .socketTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(130))
                .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(130))
        )
        .build()) {
    res = client.invoke(request);
    lambdaResponse = res.payload().asUtf8String();
}
```

Why is this error thrown?

Comment: Even with the try with resources block I'd catch the Exception to be able to log better.  This error most often occurs when you've tried to reuse the pool after it's been shutdown but that's not clear from the code yet.

Comment: This is the only code that does anything to do with this. Nothing is performed after. It just creates the LambdaClient, makes the request, then closes. It works for a certain amount of time then starts failing so I can't get any more logs until it next happens. 
There must be global state where the connection pool is closed but I don't see how this code would cause it.